# Twitter API: how to know what application was used to follow

Tags: twitter

In the email notification we can see something like

```
<username> followed you using <appname>.
```

It is great. But is there any possible way to know the application name using API?

Comment: Wow, that's interesting! I didn't know that. (I've been turning off email notifications)

Comment: Update, August 2012: this is not available anymore, right?

Comment: @julien_c: what exactly?

Comment: Twitter doesn't send this info in email notifications anymore?

Comment: @julien_c: it does. Just got it today morning

Comment: @zerkms Would you care to post an anonymized screenshot or email source so that I can see where it should be located? Haven't been able to find it.

Comment: @julien_c: sure. It was a mass-follower though ;-) http://i42.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0803/97/ad16a001e088fc0e96731e514c74fb97.png

Comment: @zerkms I don't get it: where does it say which application was used to follow?

Comment: @julien_c: oh, I see now. Sorry didn't get you. Well, seems like they've removed it, yep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look through the REST API, and I could not find anything that would support this. My guess is that this is a twitter.com feature that is available in the API (yet).

The most logical places I looked were *statuses/followers* and *friendships/show*.  In both cases there was nothing definitive.  Checking the follower emails for my account, I found multiple followers that used applications (like PeopleBrowr and SocialOomph) to follow the account.  In *most* cases, the **source** on their latest `status` object matched the application name used to follow me, but that was definitely not a sure thing.

So, to answer your question directly, no I don't think it can be done through the API (not unless there's an undocumented method out there that does this.)

I can, however, think of a way to get that info. One approach would be to set up the email account receiving the follow notifications to forward a copy to a mailbox that is checked by an automated process. When emails show up, parse them to find the app name used to follow you.

I used the following regular expression (in C#) to find the application's name and URI in the email's body:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"followed you using\s*<a[^""]+""(?<appUri>[^""]+)""[^>]+>(?<appName>\w*)</a>");
```

I used `m.Groups["appName"].Value` to pull out the application name, and `m.Groups["appUri"].Value` to pull out the URI from the match.

In order to tie the app info to a user, I had to also find the screen name with:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(user, @"\(@<a[^>]+>(?<screenName>\w*)</a>\) is now following");
```

I used `m.Groups["screenName"].Value` to extract the value from the match.

Comment: Yes, I also thought about forwarding solution. But for public service it is not a way to follow, since email can be simply fabricated, so we cannot trust this information. anyway, +1

Comment: @zerkms - Yep, that's true. I just wanted to illustrate that it *could* be done, just not via the API. By the way, I think what you want to do should be supported, so I [opened an issue](http://code.google.com/p/twitter-api/issues/detail?id=2072) for this up on Google code. Feel free to go over there and vote it up!